# ElasticSearch ingest node grok parsing issue

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, grok

I am trying to extract the text between two parentheses.  Example: give me (green)  I only want to store "green" Here is my pipeline statement:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/xxx/pipeline/es' -d'
{
  "description" : "extracts information from parentheses ",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "grok" : {
        "field": "myfield",
        "pattern": "\\(([^)]+)\\)"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

I added the double "\" for parsing so the statement made it into ElasticSearch.  ES is now tossing me this error in the log:

> MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized character escape '(' (code 40) at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.InputStreamStreamInput@3f3f97ba; line: 8, column: 21]];

I am pulling my hair out here...  I was hoping this would be straight forward;, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And if you pass `"pattern": "[(]([^)]+)[)]"`?

Comment: looks like I am not getting any log errors (Thank you!) but it doesn't seem to be saving the results into the field.